# Oracle: breaking down data

Tags: oracle

I need to get a query to get the below data:

[image]

to display like below:

[image]

basically adding a new column Vehicle_size for each value that is listed in the corresponding column. for example.

```
kay_SM = Vehicle_size(Small)
kay_LG= Vehicle_size(Large)
Lola_SM= Vehicle_size(Small)
lola_LG= Vehicle_size(Large)
```

at the same time create a new column:competitor, identifying if it is either for "lola" or "kay"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. Please [edit] your question and add what you've tried as a [mcve]. What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: sure, I was having a hard time formatting it, therefore I just removed my code all together, I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unpivot` in this case.

```
SELECT U.RENTAL_DATE,U.OUTBOUND,U.INBOUND,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(VEHICLE_COMPETITIOR, '[^_ ]+', 1, 2) AS VEHICLE_SIZE,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(VEHICLE_COMPETITIOR, '[^_ ]+', 1, 1) AS COMPETITIOR,
RATE 
FROM T
UNPIVOT (
          RATE FOR VEHICLE_COMPETITIOR IN (KAY_SM  AS 'Kay_Small',
          KAY_LG  AS 'Kay_Large',LOLA_SM AS 'Lola_Small' ,LOLA_LG AS 'Lola_Large')
        ) U
```